# Display Web Content Title instead of "Web Content Display"

Tags: java, content-management-system, liferay, portlet

when I add a Web Content Display to my Page the Portlet is titled "Web Content Display".

So how to tell Liferay that it should use the title of the displayed Web Content.

Comment: Well that is an idea! Unfortunately, there is no automatic mechanism I know of right now that would do that. You can, however, title it yourself manually by click on the title or in the `Look and Feel` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea I can think of is to hide the title "Web-content Display" through `Look and Feel` of the portlet and then create a web-content using `Structures & Templates`.

And in the `Template` you can specify the `title` to be display at the top of the web-content and you can use some css-magic to position it where the `portlet-title` used to appear. It should not be difficult I think.

```html
<!-- position this div with the help of CSS to give the feel of the title -->
<div class="temp-title">$contentTitle</div> 
<div class="content">$myContent</div>
```